# PHP Dynamic variable (MySQL) Switch

Tags: php, mysql

I run into an error, I can not explain to myself. The `$cats['category_id']` is a MySQL Integer-Value and I want, based on that value, to set the description of the cat.

```
$properties=array();
$properties['description'] = '<strong>Your cat is:</strong> ' .

switch ($cats['category_id']) {
    case 0:
        echo "black";
    case 1:
        echo "white";
    case 2:
        echo "grey";
}
  . '<br />';
```

Here is the extract I do not get along with. How do I create a "case" statement, so the `$properties['description']` is "dynamical" (Based on the $cats['category_id'])
If I use `$cats['category_id']` on its own, like this:

```
$properties['description'] = '<strong>Your cat is:</strong> ' . $cats['category_id'] . '<br />';
```

I do get the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use break at the end of each case. So it would look like this:

```
$properties=array();
$properties['description'] = '<strong>Your cat is:</strong> ';

switch ($cats['category_id']) {
  case 0:
    $properties['description'] .= "black";
    break;
  case 1:
    $properties['description'] .= "white";
    break;
  case 2:
    $properties['description'] .= "grey";
    break;
}
$properties['description'] .= '<br />';
```

Your syntax was also wrong. You were concatenating strings with a switch statement. That is not allowed.

Comment: Dear Patrick, thank you. I still have the same error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SWITCH

Comment: With my exact code? I just tried it on my own server and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Write a color name to some variable, for instance `$color` in every case. Then use:

```
$properties['description'] = '<strong>Your cat is:</strong> ' . $color . '<br />';
```

Comment: Although your code looks more clean, you didn't explain what exactly he was doing wrong (no `break` in his switch statement). I didn't use this cleaner way in order to keep the code as close to the original as possible.

Comment: Yes, I saw that you explained problem with `break`, so I didn't want to repeat the same.